# Не отображаются svg иконки в android

Tags: android, qt, svg

Пишу мобильное приложение на Qt 5.7, в нём имеются svg иконки. Во время запуска приложения на компьютере все отображается корректно, но запуская на смартфоне svg иконки не отображаются хотя остальные изображения работают корректно. Версия android 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все решилось добавлением "svg" в .pro файл проекта